# OCaml - Implement nested functions

Tags: ocaml

I want to implement the nested functions which are recursive. How to do that?
I am getting an error in the following code "an operator expected"

```
let powerset_cf f1 = if (let rec f lst = match lst with 
                                  [] -> true
                                  | h::t ->  if (f1 h) then (f t) 
                                             else false ) then true
                     else false;;
```

Here,
      lst = any list (e.g [1;2;3])
      f1 any characteristic function which returns true if the element is in the set defined by characteristic function. (e.g. let f1 x = (x mod 3 == 0  && x<=15);; )
The powerset_cf function returns true if the lst is the member of the power set of the characteristic function.

Please help fixing this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The internal `let rec` should be a `let rec`  ... `in` ... and you are lacking the `in` ... part. BTW, be sure to indent properly (for readability reasons) your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let powerset_cf f1 lst =
  let rec f lst = 
    match lst with
      | []   -> true
      | h::t ->  if f1 h then f t else false
  in
  if f lst then true else false
;;
```

Of course we can simplify the code, but that's not the question asked.

Comment: Actually, this is a "code review" site. So I think it's appropriate to say "don't use `if-then-else` to return `true` and `false` when you could just return the conditional.

Comment: @RichN, this is not a code review site, there is a [special one](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ocaml/). But I totally agree with your comment about `if-then-else` :)

Comment: Ha! I was flipping between "Code Review" and this one and got confused. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: `if f1 h then f t else false` is more appropriately and concisely  `f1 h && f t`